# django post method create record using ListApiView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner to django rest-framework and trying to create new record using `POST` method in `ListAPIView`.

Here's my serializer:

```
from scheme.models import ProjectScheme, ProjectSchemeMaster
from rest_framework import serializers

class SchemeDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectScheme
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent_scheme_id', 'rule', 'created_on', 'created_by', 'updated_on','updated_by')
        depth=1
```

And view:

```
class ProjectSchemeList(ListAPIView):
"""
List all Schemes
"""
serializer_class = SchemeDetailSerializer
# pagination_class = ProjectLimitOffsetPagination

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    comp_logger.info('invoked scheme list all')
    schemes = ProjectScheme.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return schemes

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if serializer_class.is_valid():
        serializer_class.save()
        return Response(serializer_class.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer_class.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I get this error:

```
NameError at /scheme/schemes/
name 'serializer_class' is not defined
```

How do I pass request data to serializer_class?

Comment: If the variable is part of the class, you can't access it directly, you need to access it through the class - `ProjectSchemeList.serializer_class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created functioanlity is included by default in **CreateAPIView** generic view, or if you want to provide list and create functionality, you can use **ListCreateAPIView** which provides both. More details on DRF's generic views [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#generic-views).

```
class ProjectSchemeList(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = SchemeDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        comp_logger.info('invoked scheme list all')
        schemes = ProjectScheme.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        return schemes
```

With this definition, you won't need to manually write a post method.

If you want to manually define a post methdod, you can investiage how it is written in generic **CreateAPIView** and copy it, it's slighly different from how you want to write it. Finally, following is your version of the post method with errors fixed:

```
class ProjectSchemeList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SchemeDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        comp_logger.info('invoked scheme list all')
        schemes = ProjectScheme.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        return schemes

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Notice how we use self.serializer_class(data=request.data) instead of just serializer_class